# Quando o assunto não é sobre programação mas

Tags: suporte

Gostaria de saber em qual comunidade devo fazer uma pergunta relacionada ao meu modem por exemplo, ela não é sobre programação, porém preciso configurar algo nele pra eu poder a programar.

Procurei aqui: **MAIS COMUNIDADES STACK EXCHANGE**

Só que fiquei na dúvida se tem ou não esta comunidade específica.

Comment: Quase chegou a haver um [Super User em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=super+user) que serviria este propósito...

Comment: @Sergio, o primeiro link que cliquei diz que existia um site **Area51** em português e foi fechado é isso que entendi? No entanto existe ele na versão inglês, Lá posso fazer esses tipos de perguntas?

Comment: @Guilherme Sim, podes perguntar no [su].